# 0MQ with green threads?

Tags: erlang, zeromq

I've grown to like erlang, and it's a great (cough) architectural fit to my problem. Meanwhile I still like to imagine that I can kludge erlang processes & asynchronous message passing in python (I am currently in therapy to rid myself of this obsession).

During a recent binge I came across 0MQ & I like its messaging features. These may be self-evident to an erlang/OTP expert, but I'm just a humble python programmer (my shrink will no doubt get to read this clever argument). The [0MQ user-guide](http://www.zeromq.org/docs:user-guide#toc7) states that it uses native OS threads, and not virtual "green" threads.

1. Is there a way to make 0MQ work with say eventlet/gevent?
2. Or, should I avoid the green-eyed monster and stick to a single Python app thread, with non-blocking I/O handled by 0MQ's message queuing & its own (skilled) use of native threads?
3. Or, check out of rehab & go back to erlang?

Answer (score 3):

Responding to a stale thread because I am kind of in the same boat. Thought I would share my thoughts.

1: It looks like all the heavy lifting has already been done: https://github.com/traviscline/gevent-zeromq has integrated the gevent loop with a nonblocking zmq socket and even some Cpython speedups. It also seems to be (at the time of this writing), reasonably well maintainted.

2: It depends; if you are writing something that can use zmq without a ton of external event logic, then you should just use zmq. If OTOH you need to integrate with other protocols, you may want to use gevent (or twisted perhaps, although it has no workable zmq now at all). My projects generally require multiple protocols (ie: private queue manager, public http, public https, private memcache, etc), so I am investigating switching to gevent for quicker project turnaround than my current favorite: twisted.

3: You may want to skip zmq entirely and integrate with an existing erlang based solution like rabbitMQ; the performance advantages of zmq may not be as important as you think, and then you have an erlang message queue that easily integrates with python with existing libraries.

Also see: [Messsage Queue comparison at second life wiki](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Zero MQ now works with Eventlet:

https://lists.secondlife.com/pipermail/eventletdev/2010-October/000907.html